# appending all keys in an object to an ul jquery

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to display each key in my object into a li in a empty ul I created in HTML by using a loop. But currently I am not getting any results on the page, am I using the correct approach?

```
var myObject = { name: "nick", age: 20, gender: "male", alive: true };

for ( var i = 0; i <  Object.keys(myObject).length ; i++ ) {
     $('ul').append("<li>"myObject(i)"</li>");
}
```

On my html page I have an emmpty ul.

```
<ul></ul>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use the [for..in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop to iterate through the properties in the object.  The `for..in` loop iterates over the properties in an object. Within the loop below each property is assigned to `x`.

```
var myObject = { name: "nick", age: 20, gender: "male", alive: true };
var html = "";

for(x in myObject){
   if (myObject.hasOwnProperty(x)) {
      html += "<li>" + myObject[x] + "</li>"
   }
}

$("ul").append(html);
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/mT4P2/1

Comment: Can you explain what the x represents and how it relates to myObject? and how does the <li/>  work

Comment: @KevinBowersox can you edit the fiddle info. the updated one is http://jsfiddle.net/mT4P2/1/

Answer (score 2):

Trying to change your code at least as possible, this is a solution:

```
var myObject = { name: "nick", age: 20, gender: "male", alive: true };

var keys = Object.keys(myObject);
for ( var i = 0; i < keys.length ; i++ ) {     
   $('ul').append("<li>" + key[i] + "</li>");
}
```

As you can see, we traverse `keys` as any other array.

Cheers